# Does LLDB change the address of environment variables of C programs?

Tags: c, macos, stack, lldb

More specifically, why/how does it? I am messing with buffer overflows on my Mac and I wrote a program genv to output the memory address of the environment variables. I ended up getting 3 different addresses (obviously these will change with each run - that's not what's happening here)

SHELLCODE ADDR 1) I run the program from commandline

```
ben:~/scripts$ genv SHELLCODE
SHELLCODE                           &0x7fff5c455d3d
```

SHELLCODE ADDR 2) I run the program through LLDB and inspect the registers after setting some breakpoints

```
ben:~/scripts$ lldb genv SHELLCODE
### intermediary steps
(lldb) x/2s $rsp+0x137
0x7fff5fbffd3f: "PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal"
0x7fff5fbffd56: "SHELLCODE=helloworld"
```

SHELLCODE ADDR 3) I continue from the breakpoint and let genv output to stdout

```
(lldb) c
Process 2748 resuming
SHELLCODE                           &0x7fff5fbffd60
Process 2748 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

So 2) and 3) addresses for SHELLCODE differ by 10

```
ben:~$ python -c 'print hex(0x7fff5fbffd60 - 0x7fff5fbffd56)'
0xa
```

but 2) and 1) differ by a lot more

```
ben:~$ python -c 'print hex(0x7fff5fbffd60 - 0x7fff5c455d3d)'
0x37aa023
```

Below I have my genv program

```
// genv.c
// print address in memory of environment vars
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i;
   if (argc == 1)
   {
     printf("Improper Usage: No env args\n");
     exit(-1);
   }
   for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
   printf("%-36s%p\n", argv[i], getenv(argv[i])); // Format into columns w/ "%-36s"
   return 0;
}
```

Obviously genv's stack is being built somewhere different when it is run in LLDB and I guess that makes sense (is this to make it harder for buffer overflows and other memory-targeted hacks or something entirely different?).  HOWEVER - **why is there this offset of 10 between the register inspection and the actual printing to stdout in the same run?**

Comment: The difference between (2) and (1) of 0x37aa023 is almost certainly due to [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: OK, that's what I thought it might be. So how do I get around it? ;)

Comment: You can disable ASLR in executables you build yourself by passing the `-no_pie` option to the linker (or equivalently by passing `-Wl,-no_pie` to the compiler, which then passes that through to the linker), although that's generally not recommended except as an exercise for experimenting.  Of course, if you're trying to exploit an executable compiled with ASLR, then it's much more difficult to get around.

Comment: lol, I guess that would be the point. Thanks

Comment: By default lldb (and gdb before it) disables ASLR for programs run under the debugger on OS X.  You can turn off disabling aslr in the debugger by "settings set target.disable-aslr false".  But the default is to disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer in the `environ` array, with byte addresses.

```
0x7fff5fbffd56: "SHELLCODE=helloworld"
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      7fff5fbffd\||||||||||||||||||||
                 55555555556666666666
                 6789abcdef0123456789
```

Note that the `environ` array includes the name of the environment variable (`SHELLCODE`) as well as its value (`helloworld`) separated by an <kbd>=</kbd>. The address of the *value* is `0x7fff5fbffd60`. The difference between this and the address in the `environ` array is 10: the nine characters in `SHELLCODE` plus the <kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: Ahahaha, that is so obvious! I won't even take you down the side-roads  I took trying to account for that. Thanks a bunch